# log format for goaccess log analysis

Tags: log-analysis, goaccess

Installed goaccess, and trying to parse/analyse one log file. Facing issues in the log format. Any one knows the format we need to use - for below kind of log:[updated the log sample]

```
::1 - - [24/Jun/2013:17:10:39 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36" 0 -
```

Comment: GoAccess is a real-time **web log analyzer**. Your log looks like it's not from an access log.

Comment: @PeteDarrow Thanks for your comments. Its not an access log, its a log sample row taken from the log file created on websphere based web application.

Comment: @PeteDarrow updated the access log sample, which format should I choose for this one

Comment: try `--log-format=COMBINED` or you can try `--log-format='%h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %D %^'`

Comment: Thanks @PeteDarrow. Tried "--log-format=COMBINED" and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after using `--log-format=COMBINED`.
Answer credits to @Pete Darrow.